# Looking for something that can turn this text document back into a full file path

Tags: library, file-management, data-analysis

I am attempting to take the output of tree (which was saved into a file and passed to me [I do not have access to the original source to use something else for output]) and reconstruct a full directory path for each filename in the document.

Exert from dataset

```
¦       +-- User
¦       ¦   +-- File Backups
¦       ¦       +-- Pending
¦       ¦           +-- 2019
¦       ¦               +-- Admin.bak
¦       +-- Archived
¦       ¦   +-- Complete
¦       ¦   ¦   +-- 0903
¦       ¦   ¦   ¦   +-- 24433
¦       ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   +-- Backups
¦       ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦       +-- Pending
¦       ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦       ¦   +-- 20190306
¦       ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦       ¦       +-- 6100000.bak
¦       ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦       +-- Review
¦       ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦           +-- 15446
¦       ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦               +-- 2100000.bak
¦       ¦   ¦   ¦   +-- 3546.zip
¦       ¦   ¦   +-- SQL Backups
¦       ¦   ¦       +-- 02.11.2021
¦       ¦   ¦       ¦   +-- 7670000.bak
¦       ¦   ¦       ¦   +-- 6430000.bak
¦       ¦   ¦       +-- 4370000.bak
¦       ¦   +-- SIM Backups
¦       ¦       +--  DIFFS SIM02
¦       ¦           +-- Control
¦       ¦           ¦   +-- 6887312.bak
¦       ¦           ¦   +-- 7912007.bak
¦       ¦           ¦   +-- 5496427.bak
¦       ¦           ¦   +-- 2574206.bak
```

Example expected output:

```
User\File Backups\Pending\2019\Admin.bak
Archived\Complete\0903\24433\Backups\Pending\20190306\6100000.bak
Archived\Complete\0903\24433\Backups\Review\15446\2100000.bak
Archived\Complete\0903\3546.zip
```

Any way to recreate this to a workable data object would be welcome(JSON, XML ect). Overall it is about 2 million lines and excel failed me in being able to import and do text-to-column based on +-- delimiter

Comment: On what OS must the software run? From your use of back-slashes I assume Windows (but it could also be OS/2). Further, how much you'd be willing to spend when it came to paid software?

Comment: If there are not too many rows this could be done in Excel with only medium amount of manual work (import as text and the two types of lines as separator, then copy down the upper layer directories down in their column, then copy everything into a text editor and replace the column separator tabs by backslashes.